# PrimeNg <ptable> sorted column on page load

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

I am using primeNg `<p-table>` to display data as below:

HTML

```
<p-table [value]="documents">
        <ng-template pTemplate="header">
            <tr>
                <th [pSortableColumn]="'sName'">
                    File Name
                    <p-sortIcon [field]="'sName'"></p-sortIcon>
                </th>
               <th [pSortableColumn]="'sType'">
                    File Type
                    <p-sortIcon [field]="'sType'"></p-sortIcon>
                </th>
               <th [pSortableColumn]="sDate">
                    File Date
                    <p-sortIcon [field]="'sDate"></p-sortIcon>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-doc>
        <tr>
            <td>
                {{doc.sName}}
            </td>

        <td>
                {{doc.sType}}
            </td>
        <td>
                {{doc.sDate}}
            </td>                
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

TS

```
ngOnInit(){
    //made a service call and got data for

this.documents=[{
   "sName":"Book",
   "sType":"PDF",
   "sDate":"20-02-1999"
   },
   {
   "sName":"Book",
   "sType":"PDF",
   "sDate":"09-10-2002"
   },
   {
   "sName":"Cook Book",
   "sType":"Text",
   "sDate":"16-12-1989"
   },
   {
   "sName":"Book",
   "sType":"PDF",
   "sDate":"25-04-2000"
   },
   {
   "sName":"File",
   "sType":"PDF",
   "sDate":"02-01-1989"
   }]
}
```

My requirement is the data in `File Date` field should be sorted by default on page load. Please guide me how can I achieve this sorted `File Date` column on page load, in descending order? The sorting is working as expected but its only the sorted date is not appearing, please help me with the approach.

Comment: Why your *sDate* values don't look like dates ?

Answer (score 3):

You should add the *sortField* and *sortOrder* directives to the p-table tag like this:

```
<p-table [value]="documents" sortField="sDate" sortOrder="-1">
```

Also you could have a typo in the template when you write sDate, you have it sometimes like "sDate" others like "'sDate'" and other like "'sDate"

```
<p-sortIcon [field]="'sDate">
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of sortMode="multiple", to achieve the same results, set the following:

```
<p-table #dt ... sortMode="multiple" [multiSortMeta]="[{'field': 'organizationName', 'order': 1}]">
```